# mysql trigger vs nestjs,typeorm afterInsert

Tags: mysql, triggers, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on a project using nestjs and typeorm.

I use mysql trigger to change the value of a specific table when data is inserted or deleted.(rank)

When using mysql trigger, normal operation was confirmed.
But in order to use nestjs and typeorm functions, I want to use afterInsert() and afterRemove().

Normal operation was confirmed through afterInsert and afterRemove, is this a function that 100% matches mysql's trigger?

These functions only work in save() and remove().
Is there any way to make it work in insert() and delete() too?

And if I don't plan to change to another database, is it a good way to use mysql trigger?

Thank you!

Comment: A programming-language dependent code cannot possibly fully match the operations of a database trigger as database triggers are triggered by an operation on a database table regardless of where the data comes from, while a piece of application code can only be triggered through the application.

Comment: @Shadow I know what you said. But I'm curious if it's functionally the same.

Comment: No, it is not, see the above.

Comment: In my case, is it correct to use mysql trigger rather than afterInsert() or afterRemove()?

Comment: That depends on your requirements. If the tables in question can be updated not only through your application and you want to retain the same functionality, then you need database triggers. Otherwise, application level triggers can be fine. Your choice.